# How to add progress bar?

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

Is there a way to add progress bar in pytube? I don't know how to use the following method:

```
pytube.Stream().on_progress(chunk, file_handler, bytes_remaining)
```

My code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
# from pytube import Stream
from general import append_to_file


def downloader(video_link, down_dir=None):
    try:
        tube = YouTube(video_link)
        title = tube.title
        print("Now downloading,  " + str(title))
        video = tube.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').first()
        print('FileSize : ' + str(round(video.filesize/(1024*1024))) + 'MB')
        # print(tube.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').first())
        # Stream(video).on_progress()
        if down_dir is not None:
            video.download(down_dir)
        else:
            video.download()
        print("Download complete, " + str(title))
        caption = tube.captions.get_by_language_code('en')
        if caption is not None:
            subtitle = caption.generate_srt_captions()
            open(title + '.srt', 'w').write(subtitle)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ErrorDownloadVideo  |  " + str(video_link))
        append_to_file('debug', format(e))
    # FILESIZE print(tube.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').first().filesize/(1024*1024))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call your progress function inside the Youtube class

`yt = YouTube(video_link, on_progress_callback=progress_function)`

This is your progress function

```
def progress_function(self,stream, chunk,file_handle, bytes_remaining):

    size = stream.filesize
    p = 0
    while p <= 100:
        progress = p
        print str(p)+'%'
        p = percent(bytes_remaining, size)
```

This computes the percentage converting the file size and the bytes remaining

```
def percent(self, tem, total):
        perc = (float(tem) / float(total)) * float(100)
        return perc
```

Comment: Nothing output... :(

Comment: Now, TypeError: progress_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bytes_remaining'

Comment: what are the `chunk` and `file_handle` args for?

Comment: why are you using python 2.x?

Comment: Getting errors : TypeError: progress_function() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'file_handle' and 'bytes_remaining'

Answer (score 16):

You can also do like this without writing your own function.

code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube.cli import on_progress #this module contains the built in progress bar. 
link=input('enter url:')
yt=YouTube(link,on_progress_callback=on_progress)
videos=yt.streams.first()
videos.download()
print("(:")
```

Comment: Does this only work in cmd?
I try to use this in Pycharm but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 5):

This is something interesting!

We can emulate the download animation of linux with the following code:

```
def progress_function(chunk, file_handle, bytes_remaining):
    global filesize
    current = ((filesize - bytes_remaining)/filesize)
    percent = ('{0:.1f}').format(current*100)
    progress = int(50*current)
    status = '█' * progress + '-' * (50 - progress)
    sys.stdout.write(' ↳ |{bar}| {percent}%\r'.format(bar=status, percent=percent))
    sys.stdout.flush()

yt_obj = YouTube('<<some youtube video URL>>', on_progress_callback=progress_function)
```

Output looks like:

↳ |██████████████████████████████████----------------| 68.4%

Have fun!!

Comment: To change the appearance, I assume that you should modify `display_progress_bar` function.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is already answered, but I came across this and for me, the progress was counting down from 100 to 0. Since I wanted to fill a progress bar with the percentage value, I couldn't use this.

So I came up with this solution:

```py
def progress_func(self, stream, chunk, file_handle,bytes_remaining):
    size = self.video.filesize
    progress = (float(abs(bytes_remaining-size)/size))*float(100))
    self.loadbar.setValue(progress)
```

The loadbar is my Progress Bar from PyQt5.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

The callback function takes three arguments, not four: `stream`, `chunk` and `bytes_remaining`.

Comment: Why ? The doc for the lastest version show these three arguments : `on_progress(chunk: bytes, file_handler: BinaryIO, bytes_remaining: int)` I used stream and bytes_remaining and it works but I don't understand why !

Answer (score 3):

Here is a bit advanced version

```
def on_progress(vid, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    total_size = vid.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
    percentage_of_completion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
    totalsz = (total_size/1024)/1024
    totalsz = round(totalsz,1)
    remain = (bytes_remaining / 1024) / 1024
    remain = round(remain, 1)
    dwnd = (bytes_downloaded / 1024) / 1024
    dwnd = round(dwnd, 1)
    percentage_of_completion = round(percentage_of_completion,2)

    #print(f'Total Size: {totalsz} MB')
    print(f'Download Progress: {percentage_of_completion}%, Total Size:{totalsz} MB, Downloaded: {dwnd} MB, Remaining:{remain} MB')
```

yt.register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat shorter option:

```
yt = YouTube(video_link, on_progress_callback=progress_function)

video = yt.streams.first() # or whatever 

# Prints something like "15.555% done..." 
def progress_function(stream, chunk, file_handle, bytes_remaining):
    print(round((1-bytes_remaining/video.filesize)*100, 3), '% done...')
```

You can, of course, limit the progress output, for instance, to values like 10, 20, 30%... - just surround the `print` statement with the required `if`-clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pytube import Playlist
from pytube import YouTube

previousprogress = 0
def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    global previousprogress
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining 

    liveprogress = (int)(bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100)
    if liveprogress > previousprogress:
        previousprogress = liveprogress
        print(liveprogress)


yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zqKJBxRyuo&ab_channel=SleepEasyRelax-KeithSmith')
yt.register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)
yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add progress bar like this. ignore silly type error (if any)

```
pytube.request.default_range_size = 1048576    # this is for chunck size, 1MB size



yt = YouTube(url)
video = yt.streams.first()

video.download(<whatever>)


def progress_callback(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    size = video.filesize
    progress = int(((size - bytes_remaining) / size) * 100)
    print(progress)
    # do call progress bar from GUI here


def complete_callback(stream, file_handle):
    print("downloading finished")
    # progress bar stop call from GUI here


yt.register_on_progress_callback(progress_callback)
yt.register_on_complete_callback(complete_callback)
```