# AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'get_videos'

Tags: python, video, download, youtube, pytube

While trying to download a YouTube video from python, I come across this error `AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'get_videos'`.

Last line causes the error.

```
import pytube

link = ""
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
videos = yt.get_videos()
```

Thanks!

Comment: What made you think the object _would_ have that method? I don't see anything remotely similar in [the readme](https://github.com/nficano/pytube) or [the docs](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import pytube
link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpjREfvZiDs"
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
stream = yt.streams.first()
stream.download()
```

Try above code.
[Here](https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-download-youtube-videos-pytube/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562895/5457306) similar code which does not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Works pretty well. However, two adjoining add-ons with this.

1. Any line to show the progress of the download.
2. Could this be amended to crop only a small duration from the link and download/save that duration bit?

Thanks, again.

Comment: This is a new question altogether. I guess progress is possible but not sure of crop.

Comment: @Vallie, how do I set the download location?

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#downloading-a-video)
Specify your path in the parenthesis
download('/tmp')

Comment: A progress bar can be maintained by passing an on_progress_callback argument to the YouTube object constructor (https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185538/how-to-add-progress-bar

Answer (score 1):

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("Please copy and paste the video link here")
print(yt.title)
stream = yt.streams.first()
stream.download()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25983293)