# How to use Progress bar in pytube?

Tags: python-3.x, pytube

I want to implement a progress bar in my code, but neither the old nor the new way of implementation is working.

[How to add progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185538/how-to-add-progress-bar)
this fix dosen't work in the latest version.
Here is the latest documentation
https://pypi.org/project/pytube/

```
from pytube import YouTube
url="https://youtu.be/J5EXnh53A1k"
path=r'D://'
yt = YouTube(url)
yt.register_on_progress_callback(show_progress_bar)#by commenting this line code works fine but no progress bar is displyed
yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4').first().download(path)


def show_progress_bar(stream, _chunk, _file_handle, bytes_remaining):
  current = ((stream.filesize - bytes_remaining)/stream.filesize)
  percent = ('{0:.1f}').format(current*100)
  progress = int(50*current)
  status = '█' * progress + '-' * (50 - progress)
  sys.stdout.write(' ↳ |{bar}| {percent}%\r'.format(bar=status, percent=percent))
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to define the progress bar function, say `progress_function`:

```
def progress_function(chunk, file_handle, bytes_remaining):
    global filesize
    current = ((filesize - bytes_remaining)/filesize)
    percent = ('{0:.1f}').format(current*100)
    progress = int(50*current)
    status = '█' * progress + '-' * (50 - progress)
    sys.stdout.write(' ↳ |{bar}| {percent}%\r'.format(bar=status, percent=percent))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Then register the above defined function `progress_function` with the `on_progress_callback` as follows:

```
yt_obj = YouTube(<<youtube_video_url>>, on_progress_callback = progress_function)
```

Rest of the code follows:

```
yt_obj.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').get_highest_resolution().download(output_path='/home/myusername/Videos', filename='MyVideo')
```

Output looks like this:

↳ |██████████████████████████████████----------------| 68.4%

Have fun!!

Comment: NameError: name 'filesize' is not defined, how can I solve this error?

Comment: filesize is something which we have to set outside the function. This is the reason that was set global in function.

Comment: It is not necessary to always set it outside. You can get the filesize info from the 'chunk' parameter. So you can just use it like `filesize=chunk.filesize`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using progressbar2

```
def progress_Check(stream = None, chunk = None, file_handle = None, remaining = None):

        percent = file_size - remaining + 1000000   

        try: 
            # updates the progress bar                                   
            bar.update(round(percent/1000000,2))
        except: 
            # progress bar dont reach 100% so a little trick to make it 100    
            bar.update(round(file_size/1000000,2))

yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=progress_Check)
yt = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first().download()
```

Comment: why did you add 1,000,000?

Answer (score 1):

Here is function used to download youtube video and display progress bar from shell:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube.cli import on_progress

fuchsia = '\033[38;2;255;00;255m'   #  color as hex #FF00FF
reset_color = '\033[39m'

# url is url of youtube video to download.
def download_youtube(url):

    """ Instantiates YouTube class and downloads selected video.  Uses Built-in
    pytube.cli function on_progress to show a DOS style progress bar. """
    yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=on_progress)

    # following line displays title and number of times video has been viewed. 
    print(f'\n' + fuchsia + 'Downloading: ', yt.title, '~ viewed', yt.views, 
    'times.')

    # creates download and downloads to subdirectory called 'downloads'
    yt.streams.first().download('.\\downloads\\')

    # displays message verifying download is complete, and resets color scheme 
    # back to original color scheme.
    print(f'\nFinished downloading:  {yt.title}' + reset_color)
```

Display colors were switched because the default progress bar is fairly bright.  In event video was previously downloaded the 'Finished downloading:' message will display but the progress bar won't displayed.

Please see this [Showing progress in pytube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361894/showing-progress-in-pytube) regarding the use of pytube's built-in on_progress function.

Answer (score -1):

```
# importing YouTube from pytube

import progressbar as progress
from pytube import YouTube


def progress(streams, chunk: bytes, bytes_remaining: int):
    contentsize = video.filesize
    size = contentsize - bytes_remaining

    print('\r' + '[Download progress]:[%s%s]%.2f%%;' % (
    '█' * int(size*20/contentsize), ' '*(20-int(size*20/contentsize)), float(size/contentsize*100)), end='')


url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOVAbKKSH10'
yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=progress)
video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
video.download()
```