# Adding a progress bar in pytube

Tags: python, progress-bar, pytube

I was able to add a progress bar with [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185538/how-to-add-progress-bar) using Zubo's answer. However, I wanted to only show multiples of 10 (10%,20%,30%....100%) so I added `if` statement

But, when I run the code, the outcome was printing multiples of 10. How do I code so that it only prints once?

```
def progress_function(stream, chunk, file_handle, bytes_remaining):
    percent = round((1-bytes_remaining/video.filesize)*100)
    if( percent%10 == 0):
        print(percent, '% done...')
```

The other question is for Ismael GraHms's answer, he added `self` inside the method parameter. `def progress_function(self,stream, chunk,file_handle, bytes_remaining):` However, when I ran his code, it showed an error `progress_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bytes_remaining'`. I don't quite get why his code is not running.

0 % done...
0 % done...
0 % done...
0 % done...
0 % done...
0 % done...
0 % done...
0 % done...
0 % done...
0 % done...
0 % done...
10 % done...
10 % done...
10 % done...
10 % done...
10 % done...
10 % done...
10 % done...
10 % done...
.
.omitted for space issue but same goes on for 20%,30%...
.
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...
100 % done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix is something like this:

```
progress = 0
if(progress <= round((1-bytes_remaining/video.filesize)*100)):
    print(progress, '% done...')
    progress += 10
```